# Error, even with sudo: "dd: failed to open ‘/dev/sda1’: Permission denied" (dd input piped from gzip)

Tags: 14.04, sudo, development, dd, gzip

My command which **doesn't work**:

```
sudo gzip -dc sda1.image.gz | dd of=/dev/sda1
```

returns the following error even before I've had a chance to enter my password:

```
dd: failed to open ‘/dev/sda1’: Permission denied
[sudo] password for ken:
```

I've also tried without the "-dc" options and get the same error.

However, the dd command **without gzip, using an uncompressed file, does work**:

```
sudo dd if=sda1.image of=/dev/sda1
```

It seems like the sudo is only applying to the first command and not the entire sequence of commands.  If I remain in the same terminal session and repeat the command, I don't get the password prompt (my authentication seems to persist) and yet I still get the same error (as if my authentication is not applying to the /dev write operation).  The same error occurs when executed from a /bin/sh script.

How should I construct my command(s) to uncompress my image to the device?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in a terminal window.

Answer (score 30):

You are missing `sudo` in the other side of the pipeline:

```
sudo gzip -dc sda1.image.gz | sudo dd of=/dev/sda1
```

In a `<command> | <command> | [...]` command format, each command of the pipeline which requires `sudo` should be run using `sudo`, not only the first one.

In this case you might not need to use `sudo` on `gzip -dc sda1.image.gz`, unless you don't have read permission on the file:

```
gzip -dc sda1.image.gz | sudo dd of=/dev/sda1
```

In general, if all the commands to be run in a pipeline require `sudo`, one way around having to write `sudo` in each command is to run the whole command in a subshell invoked using `sudo`:

```
sudo bash -c '<command> | <command> | [...]'
```

Comment: @KenConrad If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the mark under the upvotes count, so that other users may know that this answer worked for you and may possibly profit from it as well.

Answer (score -1):

Found this question and answer a few years later and it helped me resolve the same issue.

For future situations, it might be useful to save the command used in creating the image to a text file, along with the command needed to move the image back to another partition.

For example:

sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 | gzip > YYYYMMDD_Rasp4_Backup.img.gz

to move to a new partition:

sudo cat YYYYMMDD_Rasp4_Backup.img.gz | sudo gunzip | sudo dd of=/dev/sdb

Save those commands in a text file alongside the .img.gz file as a reminder.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1208798)